# Foreach con Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Tengo que implementar en una pagina, donde los usuarios, eligen fecha `desde: hasta:` de un input con `type="date"` por ejemplo de 5 días, la idea es que los días que hay en medio, también se tengan en cuenta, eso ya lo solucione con el siguiente codigo:

```
$start = '2024-03-11';
$end = '2024-03-15';

// generas las fechas entre el periodo
$end = new DateTime($end);
$end->modify('+ 1 day');

$period = new DatePeriod(
new DateTime($start),
new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
```

Entonces la idea es que al tener estos 5 dias seleccionados, ponerlos en un foreach y agregar toda esa info en un excel, cada dia separado por hoja.

```
// recorre las fechas
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
 $date = $value->format('Y-m-d');
```

la variable `$date` la cargo en la query en un `SELECT` que trae la info.

El problema esta, en que al generar todo el Excel, solo me trae un día. He probado haciendo solo un `echo` para ver que trae, y si me trae todo. Pero en el Excel no recorre el `foreach`.

El excel:

```
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('A1', 'APELLIDO')->setCellValue('B1', 'SEGUNDO NOMBRE')->setCellValue('C1', 'NOMBRE')->setCellValue('D1', 'TARJETA')->setCellValue('E1', 
'DNI/LEGAJO')->setCellValue('F1', 'VISITA');
$fila = 2;

 $respuesta = sqlsrv_query( $con, $query );

 while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('A1:G1')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(12);
   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
   $hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('B1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('C1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('D1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('E1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
   $hojaActiva->getStyle('F1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
   $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $rows['LASTNAME']);
   $hojaActiva->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $rows['MIDNAME']);
   $hojaActiva->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $rows['FIRSTNAME']);
   $hojaActiva->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $rows['CARDNUM']);
   $hojaActiva->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $rows['SSNO']);
   $hojaActiva->setCellValue('F'.$fila, $rows['VISITOR']);
   $fila++;
  }
}//Cierro foreach

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

No le encuentro la vuelta, en principio para saber que funciona, es agregar toda la info en una sola hoja, y luego ya ver como separarla. No se si me podrán guiar, que puedo investigar para poder avanzar.

Comment: Es importante ver que la información venga ordenada en base a la fecha, luego puedes hacer el ciclo que recorra toda la información y un while interior que consulte que la fecha sea la misma, en caso de cambiar la fecha al menos en Php excel que es una librería similar pero ya obsoleta puedes ir cambiando la hoja de la siguiente forma: setActiveSheetIndex($i) donde $i puede ser una variable que cambies cada vez que cambies de fecha.

Comment: Excelente, me sirvió mucho el consejo, y pude solucionarlo en base a eso. Muchas Gracias! pondre cuando me deje en respuesta el como quedo.